# Truncate the text and show it on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to truncate the text(with ... at the end) and on mouseover the entire text should get expanded.

I have tried to truncate by the below code. Problem with this code is, it expands the content on click of the `...` but I need it to get opened when user mouse over anywhere on p tag

```
var len = 100;
var p = document.getElementById('truncateMe');
if (p) {

  var trunc = p.innerHTML;
  if (trunc.length > len) {

    trunc = trunc.substring(0, len);
    trunc = trunc.replace(/\w+$/, '');

    trunc += '<a href="#" ' +
      'onmouseover="this.parentNode.innerHTML=' +
      'unescape(\''+escape(p.innerHTML)+'\');return false;">' +
      '...<\/a>';
    p.innerHTML = trunc;
  }
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cf28w6qw/)**

I am looking for an easy way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

***PS: No CSS solution please, as it is not compatible with all browsers (IE7).***

Comment: And what is `escape` ?  can you provide a demo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Jquery Like this :

HTML :

```
<p>Some Text</p>
```

JS :

```
var lengthText = 30;
var text = $('p').text();
var shortText = $.trim(text).substring(0, lengthText).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "...";

$('p').text(shortText);

$('p').hover(function(){
    $(this).text(text);
}, function(){
    $(this).text(shortText);
});
```

**DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/1yzzbv4b/2/**

Or you can also achieve this with css3 property `text-overflow:ellipsis;`

CSS :

```
p{
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    width: 250px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

p:hover{
    text-overflow:clip;
    width:auto;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

**DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/1yzzbv4b/**

Comment: I was just about to suggest this - I don't get what browsers he wants it to work for as he says css is not compatible with all browsers and this would be compatible back to ie8

Comment: Yeah, it's a new property css3 so doesn't work on older browser but it work from IE8+ : http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-overflow

Comment: Yes That is the reason I had mentioned in question that NO CSS SOLUTION PLEASE

Comment: Ok sorry, i have update my post with Jquery Solution

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you set the class of your `p`-elements to be of `escape-text`, the following jQuery-code should work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $ps = $('.escape-text');


    $ps.each(function(i, el) {
        $(el).data('full-text', el.innerHTML);

        strip(el);
    });

    $ps.on('mouseover', function() {
        $(this).text($(this).data('full-text'));
    }).on('mouseout', function() {
        $(this).text(strip(this));
    })

});

var length = 100;
var strip = function(el) {
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.substr(0, length) + '...';
}
```

Comment: That's because JSFiddle has it's own onload-method, and the length/strip function becomes unavailable to the inner functions that I have used for `$ps`. Apply this code to your own project, and you'll see that it works.